# ChainlinkClient: StateVariable "volume" is not updated

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I am following official chainlink [bootcamp](https://docs.chain.link/getting-started/advanced-tutorial). The demo is based on `Kovan` network and `solc: 0.6`. However asof now in 2023 I am using `GoerliTestnet`, `solc: 0.8` and chainlink client `@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol` .

The issue is that, when I call `requestVolumeData()` the transaction is confirmed successfully but somehow the `callback` named `fulfillment` is not executed somehow (this is just my findings so far) hence as a result the state variable `volume` is not updated.

Below is my code and deployed contract address is also mentioned in it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;


import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {

    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public volume;
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Goerli
     * Chainlink - 0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7
     * Chainlink - ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        // setPublicChainlinkToken();
        setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
        oracle = 0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7;
        jobId = "ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }
    
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }
    
    function withdrawLink() external {
        LinkTokenInterface linkToken = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(linkToken.transfer(msg.sender, linkToken.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
    }
}

// contract deployed on GoerliTestnet at address: 0xF4d2279148183c2eE39Bf35130F567f5C51c402C
```

I tried executing the smart contract on goerli.etherscan.io and closely inspected the function calls and inputs.

I am expecting the state variable to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

After communicating with the chainlink official on the discord channel, the problem is sorted out.

The change is in `request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");` , all I needed to do is to replace dot(.) with comma(,) so the modified version will be like `request.add("path", "RAW,ETH,USD,VOLUME24HOUR");`

And boomm!! it worked and the state variable `volume` is updated.

Newly deployed contract on goerliTestnet is at address:
0xB70d35AF31E12Cc8b199139014C417694c08eC25